# Why I see on some libraries the dropdown with views in the breadcrumb, and others not?

Tags: list-view, breadcrumb

I am using sp 2010. I have 2 lists. In one list I see in the breadcrumb a dropdown with the views. In the other list I missing this dropdown. What I am missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the css getting applied using developer tools

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that there is another web part on the page "Search in Clearing Companies,..." which is the reason your breadcrumb doesn't display the views dropdown. The Page has to detect the List in order to present the view options, and since there is another web part that exists on the page PRIOR to the list, that page won't provide the view options since they don't apply to that first webpart.

If you Edit the page and remove the "search in Clearing Companies..." section then your breadcrumb/view dropdown will re-appear.

Comment: maybe you are right. I will test it and let you know.